# Delayed Job and Rails Admin: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job, rails-admin

Hi all SO users fixing bugs on Thanksgiving,

My delayed job setup is working fine, I have it running in production and development, but when accessing the users section of rails admin, I get the error

uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::Delayed::Job

Am I supposed to define a delayed job class somewhere? If so, what's the correct syntax for that? Delayed::Job or DelayedJob? I've tried doing this with no success.

I also ran the migration to create the jobs table.  Maybe there is an association between user and delayed job that is defined somewhere? Not too sure...

Here's a full trace:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::Delayed::Job):
10: 
11:   export_action = RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.find(:export, { :controller => self.controller, :abstract_model => @abstract_model })
12:   export_action = export_action && authorized?(export_action.authorization_key, @abstract_model) ? export_action : nil
13: 
14:   properties = @model_config.list.with(:controller => self.controller, :view => self, :object => @abstract_model.model.new).visible_fields
15:   # columns paginate
16:   @filterable_fields = @model_config.list.fields.select(&:filterable?)


activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:119:in `compute_type'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:233:in `association_model_lookup'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in associations'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/association.rb:63:in `call'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/association.rb:63:in `associated_model_config'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/association.rb:33:in `block in <class:Association>'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/configurable.rb:68:in `instance_eval'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/configurable.rb:68:in `block in register_instance_option'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/configurable.rb:42:in `block in register_instance_option'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/proxyable/proxy.rb:31:in `method_missing'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:113:in `select'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:113:in `visible_fields'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/proxyable/proxy.rb:31:in `method_missing'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/app/views/rails_admin/main/index.html.haml:13:in `__var_www_apps_miracleticket_shared_bundle_ruby_______bundler_gems_rails_admin____e____d__f_app_views_rails_admin_main_index_html_haml___3620510256847226470_59069620'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:156:in `block in render_with_newrelic'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:155:in `render_with_newrelic'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /home/shark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  remotipart (1.0.2) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:8:in `render'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/index.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Index>'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
  /var/www/apps/miracleticket/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-556e9032d23f/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/index.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Index>'
  (eval):8:in `instance_eval'
  (eval):8:in `index'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:524:in `_run__2345189654170037202__process_action__1989048903076684056__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:268:in `block in perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:263:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:33:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  rack-pjax (0.6.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:8:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.5.0.1) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:12:in `call'
  sass (3.2.2) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
  exception_notification (3.0.0) lib/exception_notifier.rb:40:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  remotipart (1.0.2) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:30:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3685644371886104563__call__3962699592338143344__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /home/shark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some class somewhere is associated with the `Delayed::Job` class. I'm guessing that you've got the class_name option on that association with `Delayed::Job` specified. I'm not sure how that would work in practice as `Delayed::Job` isn't an active record class. You'd really have to associate with the active record backend for delayed jobs (`Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job`).

In the first instance it'd be worth commenting out that association and seeing if it works without it. In the second instance it'd be worth rethinking how to associate your users with the jobs being processed.

Comment: You're right - I found this: has_many :jobs, :class_name => "Delayed::Job", :as => :owner

Comment: I'll try messing around with commenting that out and seeing if I can get it working by associating with Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job - thanks!